¿Cómo desplegar LLAMA3.1 en Tomcat?
Soy nuevo en la rama de IA Generativa. Soy desarrollador Java. ¿Es posible desplegar LLAMA3.1 en tomcat? Haciendo uso del modelo montado en mi windows con ollama, le he preguntado y me ha dicho que si es posible. Entonces se podría hacer uso de Llama 3 con Eclipse u otro IDE? La mayoría de información que encuentro respecto a los LLMs es en Python:
Esto es lo que me ha dicho LLAMA3:

Sí, puedes desplegar Llama3 en un servidor Tomcat. Aquí te presento
los pasos generales:
Requisitos previos

Instalar OpenJDK: Necesitarás instalar OpenJDK 8 o superior para ejecutar el servidor.
Instalar Maven: Maven es un gestor de dependencias que se utiliza en la implementación de Llama3.
Crear un proyecto Maven: Crea un nuevo proyecto Maven con el tipo de proyecto "jar".

Paso a paso

Clonar el repositorio de Llama3: Clona el repositorio de Llama3 desde GitHub o descarga los archivos manualmente.
Cambiar al directorio del proyecto: Cambia al directorio del proyecto que creaste en el paso anterior.
Ejecutar la tarea de configuración: Ejecuta la tarea mvn install para instalar las dependencias necesarias.
Crear un archivo de configuración: Crea un archivo llamado config.properties con la siguiente información:
* modelPath: Ruta del modelo Llama3 (por ejemplo, /path/to/model)
* maxContextLength: Longitud máxima del contexto (por ejemplo, 512)
Crear una clase de configuración: Crea una clase llamada LlamaConfig que cargue la información del archivo
config.properties.
Crear un servidor Tomcat: Crea un nuevo servidor Tomcat y configúralo para utilizar el contexto /llama3.
Crear una aplicación web: Crea una nueva aplicación web que utilice la clase de configuración LlamaConfig para cargar el modelo
Llama3.
Desplegar la aplicación web: Despliega la aplicación web en el servidor Tomcat.

Nota importante
El despliegue de un modelo de lenguaje como Llama3 puede requerir una
gran cantidad de recursos, incluyendo memoria RAM y procesador.
Asegúrate de que tu servidor tenga suficientes recursos para ejecutar
el modelo sin problemas.

Por ahora no uso spring IA, pues para integrarlo con mi proyecto actual, tendría que hacer una gran cantidad de actualizaciones de librerías y configuraciones.
Estoy inténtandolo les cuento cuál fue el resultado, mientras tanto, si alguno de ustedes tuviera alguna fuente o tutorial, se los agradeceré.

Hola pero puedes integrar un function calling nose si te sirva
Algo así.
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

@Service
public class OllamaService {

    private final String ollamaUrl = "http://localhost:11434/api/models/mistral"; // URL local de Ollama

    public String getModelResponse(String prompt) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // Configurar encabezados
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Cuerpo de la solicitud
        String body = "{ \"prompt\": \"" + prompt + "\" }";

        // Crea la entidad HTTP con cuerpo y encabezados
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

        // Hacer la solicitud HTTP
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            ollamaUrl,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            requestEntity,
            String.class
        );

        // Verificar si la respuesta fue exitosa
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            return response.getBody();
        } else {
            return "Error: No se pudo obtener respuesta del modelo";
        }
    }
}

tengo algunos artículos de function calling (por si te sirve claro en python pero tal vez sirva para Java
function calling
